# How to retrieve product photos and product info from (a non-working) Magento 1.3.1?

Tags: product-images, version

```
Magento 1.3.1
```

I had a store installed/running on Magento 1.3.1 on an old server. Then we setup another store (running Magento 1.9.1) on a new server. The newer server had higher versions of pHp and mySQL as it was needed for Magento 1.9.1 but these were too high versions for Magento 1.3.1 so when I had to discontinue the old server and I migrated this store running Magento 1.3.1 to the new server - it no longer works because the pHp and mySQL versions are incompatible with Magento 1.3.1 (too high). I installed the pHp selector blahblah but it only has a limited range of pHp versions so long story short - I'm looking for the easiest way to set this old store up again and I think that will be installing brand new version of Magento 1.9.3.6 on the new server (I have done that already) and then setup the Porto theme again.

### The big question is - **what is the easiest way to retrieve the product information (and product photos) from the old (Magento 1.3.1) store? I have all the files the same as they were migrated from the old server to the new and I can access them via FTP only (trying to load the front or back-end gives an Error).**

As per a request from Shyam Krishna Sreekumar - here is the Error...I know for sure that this really is related to the pHp and mySQL versions - I've been through this for many many hours when I tried to run my other Magento 1.3.1 site on the server where the pHp and mySQL versions were higher. The older Magento stores require lesser versions of pHp to run!

Here is the Error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 145 Table './mysite_shop/log_visitor' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
Trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(283): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(457): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(230): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(259): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(535): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(349): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor', Array)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(251): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(157): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1167): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(301): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(410): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(45): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(356): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(247): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(158): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(457): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(69): Mage::run('mysiteisbestpro...', 'website')
#17 {main}
```

Comment: please share your error as well. If the admin is not getting, you might need to export data directly via phpmyadmin or via writing a script to take it. Images can be found in media/catalog/product.

Comment: Shyam Krishna Sreekumar: Thank you for trying to help. I have spent too many hours trying to run my other Magento store 1.3.1 on higher php (and mySQL) versions and now I am certain it cannot be done. At the same time I am not able to change those versions on the server so this is not a path I can work with. I will download the images - thanks again for that. How about just the product names, possibly prices? Any way to get that out of the database? Thanks...

Comment: ofcourse its possible. did you succeeded?

Comment: Shyam Krishna Sreekumar: No - not yet...I'm pulling my hair out now because there were more stores setup there and the one I'm trying to retrieve was not even the default one. If I go to the database through cPanel - can I find that specific store and product information (which product photos were part of this store together with the product name and price?) Would that be possible? Thank you for helping...

Comment: https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/list-of-product-tables-in-magento/

Comment: please check this link.

Comment: Shyam Krishna Sreekumar: I am in phpMyAdmin right now...I looked for catalog_product_entity and it brings something up that looks like the tables but I'm not seeing actual product names etc. Is there any kind of a script, a Query I could run in there to make it present the information I am looking for? Thanks again...

Comment: SELECT `value` AS product_name
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') 
AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'));

Comment: try this to retrieve name and let me know the status.